# Getting unexpected result with criteria api in springboot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, criteria-api

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages_table")
public class MessageBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String messageId;
    private String subject;
    private String createdAt;

}
```

**Repository Class**

```
public class MessageRepository {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageRepository.class);
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<MessageBO> getMessageByID(String messageID) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<MessageBO> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MessageBO.class);
        Root<MessageBO> root = criteriaQuery.from(MessageBO.class);
        Predicate where = builder.conjunction();
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(messageID))
            where.getExpressions().add(builder.equal(root.get("messageId"), messageID));
        criteriaQuery.where(where);
        log.info(criteriaQuery.toString());
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

    }

}
```

I am trying to fetch the result based on **messageid** which is provided by user. It is working fine when I am passing existing **messageid** but when I tried with non existing message id - still I am getting details of existing **messageid**.

> I only have one record in messages_table

**I am using java17 and springboot3**

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Why are you even using the CriteriaAPI here? Just use `entityManager.find(MessageBO.class, messageID)` you are looking for the primary key so why make it more complex then that. But as it is only one argument and if you really want the Criteria API for this (which I strongly recommend against) I would remove the conjuction and just do a simple `where` in the `if` statement.